# How do you send data from a form to a class?

Tags: c#, forms, class

I have a Class named Testing and a Form called TitleScreen. In TitleScreen I have a textBox1  who's text I would like to be passed to a Class and then pass it back to my Form into a textBox2.

I know how to do only the basics in C# so if you try and make it simple as possible.

Comment: You should pick a book to learn how to do this, if we show you the code, will you understand it? You cant learn programming using google and [so] alone. [Free Programming eBooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Comment: Windows Forms? Web Forms? WPF? SilverLight? What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Class:

```
public class Class1
    {
        public static string SeparateName(string fullName)
        {
            string[] wordsInText = fullName.Split(' ');
            return wordsInText[0];
        }
    }
```

In your Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = Class1.SeparateName(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

"I highly recommend that you read a book or tutorial that targets new users, otherwise there will be holes in your understanding of the language and the frameworks."

Comment: Thanks. This works and helps. I am reading a little from tutorials and beginner guides but I find I'm not really gaining much from them. I prefer to learn as I go and come here and ask questions :)

Comment: Also, Im knew here. Is there anything I should do know that I have my answer?

Comment: ALso, since you made it simple for me. Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to perform an operation on the textbox's value and then print the result in another textbox.

You can write a method (function) that accepts an argument of type `String` and perform the operation in that method. The method can then set the `Text` property of the textbox to the result.

If you're asking how to input code in a winforms project, you can double-click the background of the form to reach its code. (At least in Visual Studio)

If you don't know how to do the above suggestions, I highly recommend that you read a book or tutorial that targets new users, otherwise there will be holes in your understanding of the language and the frameworks.

Comment: I am making a windows form application.  However I'm having a lot of trouble on figuring out how to pass data between forms and classes. I was hopping to be able to figure out how to do this better by moving the data from a textbox in my form to and from a class.

Comment: A form *is* a class, and it can be programmed in that manner. Just double click your form background and pretend it's a class like any other. You might want to instantiate the `Testing` class inside the form code, so that you can access its methods and properties.

Comment: If I initiated the class inside the form what line of code would i need to say, call a method from my form?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you want to look at the concept of data binding, whereby you bind the controls on your forms to the properties of the underlying objects (instances of your classes).

Binding removes the need to write code to cross-load the data from the class into the form and back again, instead you can then say "text box 1 is bound to this property of my class".  Then, when you update the value of the textbox the data is automatically placed into the chosen property of your class instance. Typically you then have a save button that calls a save method on your class to persist the data to your data store (database or whatever).

It is perfectly reasonable to bind more than one control on your form to the same property on your underlying class, so in your example you can bind both textBox1 and textBox2 to the same property on your class.  Then, once you've implemented databinding, when you change the value in textBox1, the value will automatically be reflected in textBox2, either on each keystroke or when the field is validated (typically when you move focus to another control).

This is the microsoft documentation on Winforms binding which covers everything you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx